# Cloned a 120GB SSD to a 256GB SSD. 256GB SSD only showing capacity of 120GB

Tags: partitioning, ssd, disk-cloning

I got a 256GB SSD and wanted to clone my original 120GB SSD to the new one. I used a software that, I assume, works at the bit-level. Now the new 256GB SSD is showing a capacity of 120GB in Windows, but in my UEFI, it still shows 256GB capacity.

I think I re-wrote the part of the SSD which tells Windows its capacity, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: You can fix that with the windows [disk management tool](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/)

Comment: Where exactly is it showing a capacity of 120 GB? And are you sure it's the SSD that's showing a capacity of 120GB (and not, for example, a volume on the SSD)?

Comment: You most likely have ~136 GB unformatted, i.e. "unallocated". As @SpidePig suggests, use a disk management tool, either that in Windows or a third-party tool such as MiniTool Partition Wizard to view disk partitions and to either resize the 120 GB partition or create a new one (e.g. "D:" drive) with the remaining unused space. Image the drive first, as a mistake in partitioning can mess up a disk.

Comment: @David Schwartz in Disk Managment it says Disk 0 (the ssd) is 120GBm with no unallocated space.

Comment: *"I used a software that, I assume, works at the bit-level."* -- What is this "secret" software that you won't name?  If the original disk used MBR partitioning and you copied that MBR to the other drive, then I would expect the results you describe.  Not sure if GPT has the same issue, but it's likely because of the protective MBR sector.

Answer (score 1):

-Click on Start, right-click on the Computer icon and choose Manage from the menu to get the computer management console.

-Click on Storage on the left.

-Click on Disk Management on the left.

On the right you should be able to see the disk partitions, create a new partition on the disk unallocated space.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Disk Managment says Disk 0 (the ssd) is 120GB and it has no unallocated space.

Comment: Assuming you still have your data on the 120GB disk, can you not delete this partition on the SSD? you should see the 256GB space, create partition size 120GB, clone disk to this partition, afterwards create another partition on the unallocated space, or extend the 120GB partition into the unallocated space.